# Find pattern in recursion

Tags: summation, recursive-algorithms, pattern-recognition

this is a example from my book

Write several elements of the recursion, and see if you can find a pattern.

T(n) = T(n – 1) + n

T(n –1) = T(n – 2) + (n –1)

T(n –2) = T(n – 3) + (n –2)

T(n –3) = T(n – 4) + (n –3)

Now substitute:

T(n) = T(n – 1) + n

= [T(n – 2) + (n –1)] + n

= [[T(n – 3) + (n –2)] +(n –1)] + n

= [[[T(n – 4) + (n –3)] + (n –2)] +(n –1)] + n

= T(n – k) + Σki=1(n –i+1) = T(n – k) + nk – ((k – 1)k)/2

I dont understand how they got

T(n – k) + nk – ((k – 1)k)/2

How did they go from this line

= [[[T(n – 4) + (n –3)] + (n –2)] +(n –1)] + n

to

= T(n – k) + Σki=1(n –i+1) = T(n – k) + nk – ((k – 1)k)/2

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line just above "I don't understand how they got" is incorrect (or at least confusing). You have the pattern
$$\begin{align}
T(n)&=T(n-1)+n\\
  &=T(n-2)+(n-1)+n\\
  &=T(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n\\
  &=T(n-4)+(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n
\end{align}$$
and it appears that
$$
T(n)=T(n-k)+[(\color{red}{n-k}+1)+(\color{red}{n-k}+2)+\cdots+(n-1)+n]
$$
We can write the part in brackets as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k(n-k+i)
$$
and recognize that this is 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k(n-k)+\sum_{i=1}^ki=(k(n-k))+\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
$$
Note that the first sum on the left is just the sum of $k$ copies of $n-k$ and the other sum on the left is just the sum $1+2+\dots+k$. A bit of simplification on the right gives you
$$
T(n)=T(n-k)+nk-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}
$$
as required.